# Make sure the regex match doesn't start with a dash

Tags: python, regex

This Python regular expression can match consecutive numbers:

```
\d{6,}(?=\D)(?![.@])|\d{6,}(?=$)
```

but I don't want the match to start with `-`, for example:

> **010-12345678** => invalid
>
> **12345678** => 12345678

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try-

```
(?<!\d|-)\d{6,}(?=\D)(?![.@])|\d{6,}(?=$)
```

Demo-

```
>>>s="""010-12345678 => invalid1234567333 => valid"""
>>>re.findall(r'(?<!-|\d)(\d{6,}(?=\D)(?![.@])|\d{6,}(?=$))',s)
>>>['1234567333']
```

[<kbd>LIVEDEMO</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/pR9mX8/2)

Comment: why need to add `\d`? if just add `(?<!-)`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Then first decimal will be escaped, see the demo e.g. `010-12345678` will be `2345678` and it will pass?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make sure that the character before the match is not a dash by using a negative lookbehind

```
(?<!-|\d)
```

as well as the negative lookahead

```
(?!-)
```

So, for example, you can use this instead

```
(?<!-|\d)(\d{6,}(?=\D)(?![.@])|\d{6,}(?=$))(?!-)
```

The lookbehind assures that there is not a `-` or digit before the original regex, ensuring that `1-000000` is not matched.

The lookahead assures that there is not a `-` after the original regex, ensuring that `000000-1` is not matched, either.

You have to wrap your original expression in parentheses, otherwise the lookbehind only takes action on the first option, `\d{6,}(?=\D)(?![.@])`, and not the second one, `\d{6,}(?=$)`.

You can test this regex [here, at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rP2xE9/2).

Comment: Oh, so you want to make sure that the string has no dashes in it? I'll update the answer

Comment: Yes, i hope the string doesn't start with dashes.